# How to split a string in scala?

Tags: string, scala, split

I have a below string which I want to parse in `Scala`.

```
word, {"..Json Structure..."}
```

In `python` I can split the string giving `(", {")` as an argument.However, `Scala` is not accepting space as an argument.

Can you guys please help me with the query?

Comment: use the split method.  Please post the exact code and error message if you need more help than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala string split method uses regular expression, `{` is a special character in regular expression which is used for quantifying matched patterns. If you want to treat it as literal, you need to escape the character with `, \\{`:

```
val s = """word, {"..Json Structure..."}"""
// s: String = word, {"..Json Structure..."}

s.split(", \\{")
// res32: Array[String] = Array(word, "..Json Structure..."})
```

Or:

```
s.split(""", \{""")
// res33: Array[String] = Array(word, "..Json Structure..."})
```